# Creating a number of functions that need to be able to call each other in Python

Tags: python, arguments, function

So first let me say that I am a novice at Python and functions seem to be out of my comprehension for the moment but where I am having trouble is having 3 functions be able to call each other.  Here is my code(yes I know it is terribly wrong but you should see where I am going):

```
def menu():
    count=gearboxes
    cost=subtotal
    return subtotal


def quantity():

    gearboxes=raw_input("How many gearboxes would you like to order? ")

    return menu()



def subtotal(cost):
    if (gearboxes<=10):
        cost=gearboxes*100.0
        print cost
    elif (gearboxes>10 and gearboxes<20):
        cost=(gearboxes-10)*80.0+1000.0
        print cost
    elif (gearboxes>20):
        cost=(gearboxes-20)*70.0+1000.0+800.0
        print cost
    else:
        print "wtf m8"

    return menu()

def summary():
    print "="*80
    print "%60s %20f %20f" % ("motors",count,cost)
    print "="*80


print quantity()
print subtotal(menu)
print summary(menu)
```

There is it and any help would be greatly appreciated if you could explain also kind of how functions call on each other.

Thanks!

fixed version(still working)

```
    def quantity():
        motors=raw_input("How many motors would you like to order? ")
        gearboxes=raw_input("How many gearboxes would you like to order? ")
        sensors=raw_input("How many sensor boards would you like to order? ")

        return int(motors),int(gearboxes),int(sensors)



   def subtotal(motors,gearboxes,sensors):

        if motors<=10 and gearboxes<=15:
            motorCost=motors*100
            gearboxCost=gearboxes*50
            sensorCost=sensors*66
            return motorCost, gearboxCost, sensorCost

        if motors>10 and motors<=20 and gearboxes>15 and gearboxes<=30:
            motorCost=(motors-10)*80+1000
            gearboxCost=(gearboxes-15)*40+750
            sensorCost=sensors*66
            return motorCost, gearboxCost, sensorCost

        elif motors>20 and gearboxes>30:
            motorCost=(motors-20)*70+1000+800
            gearboxCost=(gearboxes-30)*30+750+600
            sensorCost=sensors*66
            return motorCost, gearboxCost, sensorCost

    def summary(motors,gearboxes,sensors,motorCost,gearboxCost,sensorCost):
        print "="*80
        print "%60s %20d %20d" % ("motors",motors,motorCost)
        print "%60s %20d %20d" % ("gearboxes",gearboxes,gearboxCost)
        print "%60s %20d %20d" % ("sensor boards",sensors,sensorCost)
        print "="*80


   def menu():

        a,b,c=quantity()
        d,e,f=subtotal(a,b,c)
        summary(a,b,c,d,e,f)
        return


    menu()
```

Comment: Which part of [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.  Treat a function like a question.  When you call the function; you're asking the question.  What you pass to `return` is the answer to the question.  So when someone asks for the `subtotal` of some number of gearboxes; we return `cost`, whatever that may be.

We can then store the return values (the answers) in variables and use them later.  For example, to pass to another function.  Try to follow how information flows through the program.

```
def quantity():
    count=raw_input("How many gearboxes would you like to order? ")
    return int(count)



def subtotal(count):
    if count<=10:
        cost=count*100.0
        return cost
    elif count>10 and count<20:
        cost=(count-10)*80.0+1000.0
        return cost
    elif count>20:
        cost=(count-20)*70.0+1000.0+800.0
        return cost

def summary(count, cost):
    print "="*80
    print "%60s %20f %20f" % ("motors",count,cost)
    print "="*80

def menu():
    items = quantity()
    sub = subtotal(items)
    summary(items, sub)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

Comment: You can replace `elif` by just `if`.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to improve this code (I can take a stab at it if there's any interest), but `elif` is correct there.  It skips the evaluation of the condition if one of them has already matched.

Comment: What refaim's saying is that return will break you out of the function anyway so, while more correct in spirit, elif does nothing more than 3 if blocks.  In fact, you could just move the `return cost` to the end and not repeat so much code.  As you said, lots of ways to improve the code and the general guidance you gave on functions is solid.  This feels like a homework problem so I'd hesitate to rework this into an ideal solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  it was very helpful however i am required to have a 4th function titled menu that is suppose to "act as a data exchange between the other three functions, parameters and return values will come and go from here"  That I am also confused with.  How would I go about created a function that works in that way?

Comment: That sounds like you want those last three lines to be in your menu function.  (I updated the post to work like this.)  If you don't know about the last part, read [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help rain.. I've updated the code to a working version with more added just for everyone to see but you've def helped me understand functions alot better.

Answer (score 0):

"subtotal" already calls menu() so I'm not sure what you are asking since you are already calling one function within the other.

Also, I can't see what your program is supposed to do - if your function names would be verbs (print_menu, get_menu, set_menu, throw_menu_on_moon, calculate_subtotal, ...) it would be better to understand for humans.

Also, the names you use (on the right hand side of =) within a function must be known there, so for example

```
def menu():
    count=gearboxes
```

makes no sense (because "gearboxes" is unknown - on the other hand, "count" is fine since it defines new variable - since it is on the left hand side of =)...

Note that variables are only known within the function you defined them in, so

```
def f():
    gearboxes = 2
def menu():
    count=gearboxes
```

would make no sense either.

But

```
def f():
    return 2
def menu():
    gearboxes=f()
    count=gearboxes
```

would make perfect sense.

Read the

```
def calculate_subtotal(gearbox_count):
```

as "to calculate subtotal of gearbox count do".

If you then say anywhere outside:

```
calculate_subtotal(5)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then the underlined part will be replaced by the result returned.

Otherwise, in Python the lines (in a block) are executed one after another - if you want to do multiple things in sequence, you can just write them one line each, one after another.

"return" is not "goto", "return" gives back the result - and control - to the caller of the function. Then the result is placed into the program "instead of the call".